# How to calculate the time complexity of given reccurence relation, Big-Oh notation?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to find the big-oh notation of

> T(n)=n*T(n-1)

where T(1)=1
is the answer O(n!) or O(n^n)?

Comment: You can solve this recurrence relation directly: it's T(n) = n! If T(n) represents a runtime of an algorithm, then that algorithm is O(n!). It's also O(n^n), because n! is in O(n^n), but that's not a tight bound.

Comment: @PaulHankin so according to you O(n!) is the precise answer and O(n^n) is also an answer but its not tight bound. am i right?

Comment: O(n!) is a tight bound, and O(n^n) is a loose bound. That means T(n) = Theta(n!) but T(n) is not Theta(n^n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Big-O notation technically defines sets of functions, and *upper bounds* on those sets, it is worth noting that both are *technically* correct.

A *closer*, *tighter* upper bound on the recurrence relation is

***O(n!)***

since

```
n!  = 1 * 2 * ... * n
n^n = n * n * ... * n
```

clearly shows that ***n^n*** is larger than ***n!***.

You can prove this by induction as well.

Since ***T(n+1) = (n+1) * T(n)*** which is equal to ***(n+1)!*** since you can assume ***T(n) = n!***.

Answer (score -2):

T(n) = n!

Then you get theta(n!).

Omega(n!) is correct

omega(n!) is not correct

Theta(n!) is correct

o(n!) is not correct

O(n!) is correct

o(n^n) is correct

O(n^n) is correct

Comment: it cant be O(n) in any way and its not reccurence relation of factorial i.e [t(n-1)+1]

Comment: Well why ? You dont use 2 recursion steps.

Comment: when i tried it gives n*(n-1)*(n-2)....t(n-(n-1)).so,should i take O(n^n) as it is highest degree polynomial or if you observe it looks like factorial so, is it O(n!)

Comment: If you have O(T(n)) = 1+ O(T(n-1)) you can just calculate the result by induction.

Comment: the question is n*T(n-1)

Comment: I got that. I was about calculating the runtime of the recurysion